# How to create facebook new event with cover photo

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

My facebook codes for creating new events is here;

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
Dictionary<string, object> createEventParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
createEventParameters.Add("name", "test");
createEventParameters.Add("start_time", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
createEventParameters.Add("end_time", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).AddHours(4).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
createEventParameters.Add("owner", "me");
createEventParameters.Add("description", "description");
JsonObject venueParameters = new JsonObject();
venueParameters.Add("street", "test");
venueParameters.Add("city", "test");
venueParameters.Add("state", "test");
venueParameters.Add("zip", "0000");
venueParameters.Add("country", "test");
venueParameters.Add("latitude", "100.0");
venueParameters.Add("longitude", "100.0");
createEventParameters.Add("venue", venueParameters);
createEventParameters.Add("privacy", "OPEN");
createEventParameters.Add("location", "test");
FacebookMediaObject logo = new FacebookMediaObject(){
   ContentType = "image/jpeg",
   FileName = @"J:\logo.jpg"
};
logo.SetValue(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(logo.FileName));
createEventParameters.Add("picture", logo);
JsonObject result = facebookClient.Post("/my_page_Id/events", createEventParameters) as JsonObject;
```

The code seems o.k to me but it does not upload the cover photo and I don't know why.

My sample code;

```
createEventParameters.Add("cover_url", "photo_url");
```

and this post [Facebook C# SDK, Create Event With Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024068/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-create-event-with-picture) doesnt work for me.

Could you please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** upload the cover pic while creating an event. You can upload the cover pic only after the event is created. So, two calls instead of one!

Follow these steps:

1. Create the event without any parameter related to cover pic. After the call, you'll get the **Event ID** in response.
2. Use that **Event ID** and make this call-

   API: `\POST /{event-id}`

   Parameter: `cover_url` (picture link)

That's it!

Comment: var cover_args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    var coverfile = new FacebookMediaObject
                    {
                        ContentType = PostItem.ImageList[0].Type,
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachementPath)
                    }.SetValue(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(attachementPath));
                    cover_args["cover_url"] = coverfile;
                    cover_args["access_token"] = FacebookPage.PageToken;

                    var CoverResult = fbClient.Post(resultId, cover_args); But it's not working.