# How to create an event on a Facebook Page using C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a CMS system where you can create events. The events appear on a website and this works fine, but now I want to create the same event on a Facebook Page.

I've installed the Facebook SDK for .NET and is able to get access token for a facebook app.

I've also read alot on Facebook developer, but I still dont have a clear answer to my problem. And I dont get why it seems like you hafto create a Facebook App...? Im not looking to create an app, I just want access to a page and create an event.

Comment: See how he does it in his question using the Facebook API. Note you'll have to adapt it to create it on a page which shouldn't cause problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024068/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-create-event-with-picture

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look. I know how to create the event, but I dont know how to get an access_token with access to the Page. is there any examples for .NET on how to handle all the log in logic? all the javascript is hard to debug

Comment: There is no API for creating events in API v2.0 and later. And even if you have an app that still have access to API v1.0 it will lose that at 4/30/2015

Comment: well thats disappointing